# XStreamAsAttribute not adding as attribute - xstream

Tags: jaxb, xml-serialization, restlet, xstream

I wrote a class which will be converted by xstream into xml .

I added @XStreamAsAttribute to add xmlns as an attribute . But it got added as a nested tag in  the output

My class file is as follows

```
@XStreamAlias("GetConfigurationParametersResponse")
public class GetConfigurationParametersResponse
    extends BaseResponse
{
    @XStreamAlias("xmlns")
    @XStreamAsAttribute
    final String xmlns = "http://www.collab.net/teamforge/integratedapp";

    @XStreamAlias("xmlns:ns2")
    @XStreamAsAttribute 
    final String ns2="http://www.collab.net/teamforge/integratedapp";


    @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName="ConfigurationParameter")
    protected List<ConfigurationParameter> configurationParameter;

    public List<ConfigurationParameter> getConfigurationParameter() {
        if (configurationParameter == null) {
            configurationParameter = new ArrayList<ConfigurationParameter>();
        }
        return this.configurationParameter;
    }

}
```

The output for this is as follows

```
<com.collabnet.teamforge.ia.GetConfigurationParametersResponse>
<xmlns>http://www.collab.net/teamforge/integratedapp</xmlns>
<ns2>http://www.collab.net/teamforge/integratedapp</ns2>
</com.collabnet.teamforge.ia.GetConfigurationParametersResponse>
```

But I need output as

```
<com.collabnet.teamforge.ia.GetConfigurationParametersResponse xmlns="http://www.collab.net/teamforge/integratedapp" xmlns:ns2="http://www.collab.net/teamforge/integratedapp">
</com.collabnet.teamforge.ia.GetConfigurationParametersResponse>
```

Please help in finding out where I am going wrong . 
I followed this tutorial http://x-stream.github.io/annotations-tutorial.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to do the following:

```
xstream.processAnnotations(GetConfigurationParametersResponse.class);
```

If only the following is being called:

```
 xstream.processAnnotations(BaseResponse.class);
```

Then you could use the `@XStreamInclude` annotation on `BaseResponse` as follows:

```
@XStreamInclude({GetConfigurationParametersResponse.class})
public class BaseResponse {
}
```

Comment: How can you apply `xstream.processAnnotations` in a Restlet application? First how do you get that `xstream` instant out of the configured converters?

Comment: Also, maybe you can share some idea with this Restlet issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66794041/using-xstream-extension-with-swagger-instead-of-jackson

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was:

```
xstream.autodetectAnnotations(true);
```